# Fermat-quotient of "order" 3: I found $68^{112} \equiv 1 \pmod {113^3}$ - are there bigger examples known?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

*(I've taken this from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594708), it seems to be more appropriate here)*

I'm rereading an older text on fermat-quotients (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient)) from which I have now the

***Question*** for
$$ b^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{ p^m} \qquad \text{ with $p \in \mathbb P $, $1 \lt b \lt p$ and $m \gt 2$} $$ 
(This is a generalization of the question for Wieferich primes).

Note that I ask here for examples, where the bases $b$ are *smaller* than the prime $p$, so a very well known weaker case $3^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {11^2 } $ were an example, but only if the exponent at $11$ where one more; however frequent and well known cases like $18^6 \equiv 1 \pmod {7^3} $ were not because the base is bigger than the prime.

The only example that I've found so far is
$$ 68^{112} \equiv 1 \pmod {113^3 } $$
but I've scanned only the first *2000* primes $p \in (3 \ldots 17389)$ and my primitive brute force algorithm has more than quadratic time-characteristic, so checking *10 000* or *100 000* primes were no fun - the quadratic regression prognoses *1* hour for testing *10 000* primes and *101* hours for testing *100 000* primes...

I'm aware of a couple of webpages containing lists of fermat quotients up to much higher primes, but either there is no explicite mention of the cases of $b \lt p$ and quotient $m \gt 2$ or I've been too dense when scanning through the listings ([Richard Fischer](http://www.fermatquotient.com/), [Wilfrid Keller](http://www1.uni-hamburg.de/RRZ/W.Keller/FermatQuotient.html), [Michael Mossinghoff](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~mjm/WieferichBarker/))

---

For reference: my Pari/GP-code is

```
for(j=2,2000,p=prime(j);p3=p^3;
    for(k=2,p-1,
        r = lift(Mod(k,p3)^(p-1));
        if(r==1,print(p," ",k," ",r)));
    );
```

*(One correspondent took this up to the 10 000'th prime which is $p=104729$ )*

---

[update] For the later casual reader I've included a more involved explanation and a table of data. See [here](http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquot_ge2_table1.htm) (filesize 2Mb, inconvenient for modem-transfer)

Comment: Cases b<p can be easily identified in Fischer's table http://www.fermatquotient.com/FermatQuotienten/FermatQ3 and there no other for primes below 3.6*10^8.

Comment: The question is discussed in MR2114655 (2005i:11004) Keller, Wilfrid; Richstein, Jörg; Solutions of the congruence $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^r}$,  Math. Comp. 74 (2005), no. 250, 927–936 but I don't think any solutions are found, other than the one you already have. Still, the paper might be worth a look, to see what's been done.

Comment: Thanks to Max and Gerry for the links - I could access them both and also got the article of Keller/Richstein.

Comment: @Max : if you would like to convert your comment into an answer I could mark that as accepted which would then "close the case"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cases with $b<p$ can be easily identified in Fischer's table https://www.fermatquotient.com/FermatQuotienten/FermatQ3.txt and there are no other such instances for primes below $1.1\cdot 10^9$ (updated 2024-03-13).

Comment: The current (3'2024) url is  https://www.fermatquotient.com/FermatQuotienten/FermatQ3.txt (seems we need the "https" instead only "http")

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: Thanks, I've updated my answer.